# The getEntityAttributes() function in Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I am trying to use the attributeService.getEntityAttributes function to obtain some server attributes of my device. I was using the .getEntityAttributesValues function when working with the 2.x version of Thingsboard and it was working fine. With the current version I am using the following code:

```
var conf = {
  ignoreLoading: false,
  ignoreErrors: true,
  resendRequest: true
};

var myattr = attributeService.getEntityAttributes(entityID,'SERVER_SCOPE',["myattribute"],conf);
```

But I get no data or error back. I was using the .getEntityAttributesValues with .then() method but it doesn't seem to work anymore. It says ".then is not a function".

What am I doing wrong? Please help and tell me how to use the new function properly. I am using TB v.3.1.1 CE.

Answer (score 1):

Thingsboard 2.x UI was made with AngularJS.
Thingsboard 3.x UI now uses Angular.

One of the key differences between these frameworks in regards of your problem is the move from Promise based services, to Observable based services.

Let's look at the source of the `getEntityAttributes` function:
https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/2488154d275bd8e6883baabba5519be78d6b088d/ui-ngx/src/app/core/http/attribute.service.ts

It's mostly a thin wrapper around a network call made with the `http.get` method from Angular.

Therefore, if we have a look at the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server, it is mentioned that we must subscribe to the observable in order to handle the response. So something along the lines of:

```js
attributeService.getEntityAttributes(entityID,'SERVER_SCOPE',["myattribute"],conf).subscribe((attributes) => {…})
```